# send_message from mod_admin_extra not working

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I want to send message to client from the server using send_message in mod_admin_extra
I tried the following command:

> ejabberdctl send_message "chat" user1@ip user2@ip /"hello/" /"wow/"

And I am getting the following error

```
Problem 'error undef' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{jid,from_string,[<<"user1@<ip>">>],[]},
             {mod_admin_extra,send_packet_all_resources,3,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1367}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,269}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,218}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,203}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]
```

guys any solution for this problem will be helpful for me. Thanks alot

EDIT 1

```
Problem 'error badarg' occurred executing the command.
Stacktrace: [{ets,lookup_element,[jlib,string_to_jid_pattern,2],[]},
             {jid,from_string,1,[{file,"src/jid.erl"},{line,97}]},
             {mod_admin_extra,send_packet_all_resources,3,
                              [{file,"src/mod_admin_extra.erl"},{line,1367}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,293}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,try_call_command,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,269}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process2,3,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,218}]},
             {ejabberd_ctl,process,1,
                           [{file,"src/ejabberd_ctl.erl"},{line,203}]},
             {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                  [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,205}]}]
```

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. Check send_packet_all_resources method in mod_admin_extra.erl file to debug it. Maybe try putting logger and find out what's causing the error. 

Btw have u modified anything in the module?

Comment: Actually I downloaded latest mod_admin_extra module and made some changes in ejabberd_commands.hrl file for ejabberd14.05

Comment: can u paste the line number 1367 from mod_admin_extra? If it is the latest from git then looks like you are facing issue in jlib.

Comment: FromJID = jid:from_string(FromJIDString),

Comment: You have jid.erl file missing. Compile it and put it in beam directory. This issue should be fixed. But you might still get other dependencies error.

Comment: Hi kumar i have edited the post.I am getting  the error after adding jid.erl. Do you what different dependancies are required to solve this issue??

Comment: use the following method jid_to_string from jlib.erl file at line number 1367 in mod_admin_extra.erl for any such operation. Reason u r getting so many dependencies because code hasn't been written in downward compatibility.

Comment: Hi Kumar i downloaded older version of mod_admin_extra which is compatible with ejabberd version I am using. Now I am able to use send_message_chat command using ejabberdctl. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)